# Unable to list the Container images in Cloud Run deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, spring-cloud-gcp

I have IAM roles like Editor/Cloud Run Admin in my gcp projects (multiple Projects) I am facing this issue,
When I am trying to deploy the container image from Cloud Run's "Edit & Deploy New Revision" screen.
It's not listing the Images in the Project and gives error [refer this screenshot for the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDAdm.png) .
Its not only for me other users also facing same issue, but with the same editor and admin roles I am able to list all images in the other project. I have also checked with other developers

Comment: Are you sure having the role `Editor/Cloud Run Admin` in the project containing the issue ?

Comment: My colleague got the same error today in our GCP project. Until today everything worked. My colleague has the owner role.

Comment: I faced the same issue in one project yesterday. Today I have it in two projects. It would seems GCP is making some changes to projects and/or customer accounts in batches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "Artifact Registry API" is enabled in GCP. then we can list the images from the project.
To enable this API, Search for 'Artifact Registry API' and click enable.
Only if you have this 'Service Usage Admin' IAM role, you can enable API.

Thanks to my Support Team in Project